# How do I add a list to a board using the Trello API

Tags: trello

I would like to add lists programatically. It seems that there is  a GET for boards - createList but I don't seem to be able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I find it's easier to go an alternate route.  Use the POST for lists:

```
POST /1/lists/
```

On this call, there is an option where you can add the boardId.  Using the ID for the board to which you want to add the list allows you to work your magic.